# Is serial or automatic favoriting considered abuse?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bookmarks, serial-voting, abuse

Much is said about serial voting; but I haven't seen anything about serial favoriting.

1. If I decide to follow a particular user and mark all their questions as favorite, would that be considered abuse?
2. If I run a bot that automatically favorites every new question by a user with >=1000 reputation (for example), would that be considered abuse?

Disclosure: I have no plans for doing 1. I am considering 2 as a means of enabling filtering questions by reputation of askers, since the site search supports `infavorites:userid`.

Comment: I don't see why favoriting would be abuse… It's certainly better than sorting questions by ignoring [over a thousand tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269168/2371861) :p

Comment: Why would that even remotely be considered abuse at all? Favoriting means absolutely *nothing*, especially since people favorite posts for a variety of reasons (i.e. having a question favorited does *not* mean people like it).

Comment: Abuse, no.  Creepy, yes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Much is said about serial voting; but I haven't seen anything about
>   serial favoriting.

that's because the two functions have very different affects on the site and users.

Voting on user's posts can:

- Alter where it's positioned, in the Front Page or vote sorting based
  searches, and answers are moved up or down based on votes
- Give them rep and badges, or lose them rep if dvote
- Alter their mood, if they get downvoted for what seems a decent post
  (etc)
- Various other things

The only thing favourite can "alter" is a user can earn a badge for a certain number of favourites received - *but* only based on a single question. So your single favourite is not going to be classed as "abuse" in any way.

> If I decide to follow a particular user and mark all their questions
>   as favorite, would that be considered abuse?

Abuse by whom? The user you fave doesn't know who it is which faved their question, so as far as they are concerned some "user**s**" favourited their questions.

> If I run a bot that automatically favorites every new question by a
>   user with >=1000 reputation (for example), would that be considered
>   abuse?

Within the scope of favouriting someone, this is no different than you clicking the button manually. As it's unlikely for a user to ask many questions at the same time, so you'd be favouriting questions from *different* users each time and you'd only fave a question from the same user every so often.

However, in terms of bots and scripts being run on the site, see the site's official Terms and Conditions, or ask about this specifically if you are unsure. You do have to be careful as the system might identify you are doing too many things at once (etc).
It might even block you if it runs too quickly.

> I am considering 2 as a means of enabling filtering questions by
>   reputation of askers, since the site search supports
>   infavorites:userid.

*Site policy for scripts/bots aside*, it's your choice if you want to do this.

Personally, however, I see no merit in rep at all. I've seen terrible questions, answers, and attitude from very high rep users, as much as new users.
Rep means they have received X upvotes over Y time, it is no indication that their question will be good.
Even if you find that >1k rep means quality, their rep level is surely no indication of a question being useful or interesting to you?

Seems pointless to me, but sincerely, one man's junk is another man's treasure :)

---

Favourite whoever you wish, or don't. It's just a tool to "bookmark" questions.
But do take note of site policy if you are going to run an automated bot on the site :)

Comment: I've managed to get blocked for flooding once. It's not too bad, it's just an unstyled page with a stern error message that goes away in a minute or so. I think I'm going to call it "heroku'd"